# Hazard and density function in survival analysis with discrete time

Tags: survival, density-function, discrete-data, hazard

I am running a survival analysis with descrete time. For that purpose I use the R package `survival` with this function

```
surv.km <- survfit(formula = Surv(analyse$Time, analyse$Event) ~ 1, conf.type = "log",
  conf.int = 0.95, type = "kaplan-meier", error = "greenwood", data = analyse)
```

In the following the terms, notation and symbols from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis#Survival_function) are used.

I can plot the survival function `S(t)`, the event function resp. cumulative density function `F(t)` (`fun="event"`), the cumulativ hazard function `H(t)` (`fun="cumhaz"`) and some other functions.

However, is there a way to calculate the density function `f(t)` or the hazard function `h(t)`? Both are actually defined for continuous time. At the moment I use the following formulas:

$f(t) = F(t+1) - F(t) = S(t) - S(t+1)$ where $t$ is discrete

$h(t) = \frac{f(t)}{S(t)} = 1 - \frac{S(t+1)}{S(t)}$ where $t$ is discrete

Does this make sense and is mathematical well founded? References to books or papers are welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Survival Analysis (Techniques for Censored and Truncated Data
), Klein and Moeschberger pg. 30-31, 1997, the discrete time density function would be

$P(X=t)= P(t-1<X\leq t) = P(X\leq t) - P(X\leq t-1)  = F(t) - F(t-1) = (1-S(t))- (1-S(t-1)) = S(t-1)-S(t)$ 
S(0)=1

Likewise, the discrete hazard is defined to be

$P(X=t \mid X \geq t) = P( X=t \mid X> t-1) = \dfrac{P(X=t , X>t-1)}{P(X>t-1)} = \dfrac{P(X=t )}{S(t-1)}= \dfrac{S(t-1)-S(t)}{S(t-1)}=1-\dfrac{S(t)}{S(t-1)}$